# Get two-finger scroll on Windows laptop touchpad (like on macbook)?

Tags: windows, touchpad, scrolling

I have a Dell Latitude laptop. Scrolling using the touchpad is possible by sliding along the right (or bottom) side of the touchpad. This doesn't work too well for me. Is it possible to configure the touchpad to scroll by using two fingers, just like is common on the Apple macbook family?

**Edit:** Some answers refer to the synaptic driver, however, I never found a link to a unmodified Synaptic driver (that works on Windows 7 64-bit). Any direct references to a driver **that you know will work** is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Two-finger scrolling and other gestures are built in to the latest Synaptics drivers. Two-finger tap to right-click is not built in though. There is a Google Code project called [TwoFingerScroll](http://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/) which can enable both the two-finger scrolling and two-finger tap to right click functionality. I tested it on my laptop with the latest synaptics drivers, and it worked well.

[image: twofingerscroll tap settings]

Interestingly, the scrolling enabled by this tool seems much smoother than the scrolling built into the regular synaptics driver.

Comment: Upon double-clicking TwoFingerScroll.exe I get: "No Synaptics TouchPad device found". So it seems I need the Synaptics driver, however I never got that driver to work properly . If anybody has a link to the Synaptic driver that works under win7 64-bit, I am interested...

Comment: This TwoFingerScroll report describes my issue: http://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/issues/detail?id=68

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure there are drivers for this, I haven't got any experience in this field, unfortunately.

On linux two-finger scrolling works for most touchpads, which support it, out of the box. My Latitude is able to do this.

A [quick search using Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=two+finger+scroll+windows) revealed two methods:

- Third-party program [Two Finger Scroll](http://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/).
- Patched [synaptics driver](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2009/05/31/enable-multi-touch-gesture-finger-scroll-momentum-and-chiralmotion-on-synaptics-touchpad-in-windows-7vistaxpserver/).

There are some blog articles about just this topic, I suggest first reading them.

Comment: The [two-fingerscroll](http://code.google.com/p/two-finger-scroll/) project you linked to works perfectly on Lenovo T420 laptops running windows 7.  The smooth scroll behaves almost identical to the constant feedback you get on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below link and you can get this

[Synaptics Gesture Suite™ for TouchPads](http://www.synaptics.com/solutions/technology/gestures/touchpad)

Comment: No, doesn't work