# A plugin for Windows to support Mac touchpad usability features?

Tags: windows, mac, touchpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get two-finger scroll on Windows laptop touchpad (like on macbook)?](https://superuser.com/questions/82308/get-two-finger-scroll-on-windows-laptop-touchpad-like-on-macbook)

After some experience with mac I always try to scroll or zoom using two fingers on touchpad. But there is a number of reasons preventing me from moving to macs completely. I just wonder could there be a software which make Windows touchpad a bit more macish? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/82308/get-two-finger-scroll-on-windows-laptop-touchpad-like-on-macbook

Answer (score 1):

This would be a limitation of your actual touchpad as gesture/multi touch support is something built in.

You can learn more at [Synaptics](http://www.synaptics.com/) who make most of the drivers and hardware for most laptop companies.

Also, a good source of information is the forums at [Laptop Video 2 Go](http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/), they often have "hacked" hardware drivers that can unlock additional features if they are only software locked.